# Variable Queryset filter by using a string as input

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

im working on creating a variable queryset by using a string and im not reaching the solution.

This is my method

```
output = "entradaid__in=["

for x in carrito_entradas:
    output+=x+","

temp=len(output)

output = output[:temp - 1]
output += "]"

peliculas = Pelicula.objects.filter(output)
```

What I want is create a queryset of "Peliculas" that can filter more than one value.

My intention is this:

`output=entradaid__in=[1,2,5]`.
`Pelicula.objects.filter(entradaid__in=[1,2,5])`

Is there a way where I can do this?

Comment: You can not pass a filter criterion as a string.

Comment: You can however pass a dictionary like `**kwargs`. But what is your aim? Just to check if `entradaid__in=carrito_entradas`?

Comment: as said, by building a dictionary. For example `some_dict={'entradaid__in': [1,4 2, 5]}` and then `.filter(**some_dict)`.

Comment: My aim is reach from an array all the primary keys from tickets that a user has bought and show it in another view. Ill try the dictionary **kwargs.

Comment: But you only need the kwargs if the *criteria* - eg "entradaid__in" - is variable. From what you're saying, only the values are variable - so you can just put `carrito_entradas` there directly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I have the idea that this was only meant to demonstrate that the OP wants to construct a variable query.